# Alguém sabe com ativar a funcionalidade para exportar PDF no DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, aplicação-web

Estou usando o plugin js DataTables mas não sei como ativar a funcionalidade de exportar para PDF ou Excel. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Desde já agardeço, att.

Comment: Desculpem, falta de pesquisa: https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/

Comment: Alguém quiser excluir, á vontade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trecho retirado da documentação do [TableTools](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/) do DataTables.net.

```
/*
 * Example initialisation
 */
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Já tinha resolvido @ThiagoLunardi , mas obrigado pela atenção

Comment: @Mike como voce resolveu?